# List files greater than 100K in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to list the files recursively in the `HOME` directory. I'm trying to write my own script , so I should not use the command `find` or `ls`. My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

minSize=102400;

printFiles() {
    for x in "$1/"*; do
        if [ -d "$x" ]; then
            printFiles "$x";
        else
            size=$(wc -c "$x");
            if [[ "$size" -gt "$minSize" ]]; then
                echo "$size";
            fi
        fi
    done
}

printFiles "/~";
```

So, the problem here is that when I run this script, the terminal throws `Line 11: division by 0` and `/home/gandalf/Videos/*: No such file or directory`. I have not divided by any number, why I'm getting this error?. And the second one?

Alternatively, I can't use `find` or `ls` because I have to display the files one by one asking to the user if he want to see the next file or not. This is possible using the command `find` or `ls` or only can be done writing my own function?

Thanks.

Comment: `"/~"` is _literal_ `/~`, because tilde expansion only happens in _unquoted_ strings, but even unquoted `/~` wouldn't work, because `~` must _start_ the string in order to expand to the home dir.

Comment: So replacing "/~" with "/home" will work?

Comment: For your alternative, you could add whatever logic you like with `find ... -print | while read f; do ...(logic here)...; done` or (bash-specific) `while read f; do ...(logic here)...; done < <(find ... -print)`

Comment: If there is a `/home` dir., then yes (it sounds like there is), but that will search the home dirs. of _all_ users. If you just want your own home dir., use just `~`. Also note that a pattern (glob) that doesn't match anything is left unexpanded by default, causing the `for` loop to enter with a single string that refers to a non-existing path. Use, e.g., `shopt -s nullglob` to prevent that.

Comment: Don't use `wc` to get file size. Use `stat -c %s`.

Comment: @aragaer, `stat` is not portable. E.g. on Mac OS it'll be `stat -f %z` instead

Comment: The point is that `wc` _reads_ the whole file, while `stat` just gives you file size. You can use `ls` with `cut` or some other way to get the size directly. Just ... not `wc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
size=$(wc -c "$x");
```

That's the line that is failing. When you run that `wc` command manually you should be able to see why:

```
$ wc -c /tmp/out
5 /tmp/out
```

The output contains not only the file size but also the file name. So you can't use `$size` with the `-gt` comparator on the next line. One way to fix that is to change the `wc` line to use `cut` (or `awk`, or `sed`, etc) to keep just the file size.

```
size=$(wc -c "$x" | cut -f1 -d " ")
```

A simpler alternative suggested by @mklement0:

```
size=$(wc -c < "$x")
```

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks I have added that suggestion.